# Django: render a word document that is saved in a query object

Tags: html, django

I have an app where in my models.py I included a welcome text:

```
welcome_text = models.FilePathField(path="/text")
```

The file is located at app/static/text/welcome_text.docx

I thought I could use `{{app.welcome_text}}` in my html-template, but it doesn't give anything back.

Which pre-and suffix can be used to define a word document? Is it possible to render the word document that is correctly saved in the database ?

Comment: ``{{app.welcome_text}}`` will give you document name if you want full path of your document than add this ``{{app.welcome_text.url}}``

Comment: And what is the prefix and suffix ?

Comment: Do you need to render the link to the document or the document's content itself?

Comment: @YevgeniyKosmak the content itself…